# How do I create complex equation?

Tags: equations

I need to create a couple complex equations and most of the things I try end up putting the denominator next to the numerator. I am trying to create these equations:

```
k=(QL)/(t(Delta)hA)
```

and

```
k=((aL)/(At))ln(h(sub zero)/h(sub t))
```

Is it possible to make these equatons?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  You can use something like `\[ k = \frac{a}{b} \]` to obtain a fraction, `h_0` for subscripts (in math mode).  An excellent reference for math mode is Herbert Voss'  [comprehensive review of mathematics in (La)TeX](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/).

Comment: If *Is it possible to make these equations?*? It is possible to things that we can not imagine!! Welcome to TeX world.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and to the wonderful world of `LaTeX` :) Please read [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11) and the links within :)

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to have something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
    k &= \frac{QL}{t\Delta hA} \\
    k &= \frac{aL}{At} \ln \frac{h_0}{h_t}
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

There's a free tool called [Web Equation](http://webdemo.visionobjects.com/home.html#equation) that lets you write what you want (with the mouse/stylus) and it will show you the result (bottom left) along with the LaTeX code (just above the rendering); simply copy into your document (make sure you're in math mode). If you make a mistake you can press the arrow in the upper left corner to "undo/redo" some strokes. It will allow you to quickly get results while you're learning the complexities.
[image]

Comment: No automation, please :) It will turn against you later. Just learn to _know_ how to type the code, and you'll be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Another online tool web site. [www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor](http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor) It's like word equation editor.

[image]